# Laravel Vapor Deployment Permission Denied

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, laravel-vapor

I've started to transition to using Laravel Vapor, but having trouble actually deploying.

A user has been created with AdministratorAccess, network and environments created etc, but it fails when it comes to deploying.

The deployment artifact gets to S3 but then when it goes to do the assets I get a 403 Forbidden error

SignatureDoesNotMatch
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.